# How to load the recycler view adapter on resume event

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment which displays a list in recyler view (chargeHistoryList).  all the code is written in `onActivityCreated`, so this gets called only once when the fragment is called. onResume method is pretty blank at the moment.

Issue I am having is, when I initially open this fragment `ChargeHistoryFragment` recyclerview is loaded correctly with data. when I put the app in the background and comeback to it the recyclerview is empty, no data is shown.

I tried adding the code in `onViewCreated` but that also gets called only once and `onresume` is the only lifecylce method thats gets called when the app goes in background and comes back to foreground.

How can I make the adapter load with data when only `onResume` is called

ChargeHistoryFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.charge_history_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    baseActivity?.updateAppBar(title = screenTitle)

    chargeHistoryList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    chargeHistoryList.addItemDecoration(VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(8))

    onChargeSelectListener = activity as OnChargeSelectListener

    var chargeHistoryAdapter = ChargeHistoryDataAdapter(dateFormatter,
        decimalFormatter,
        timeFormatter,
        onItemClickListener = this,
        currencies = listOf())
    chargeHistoryList.adapter = chargeHistoryAdapter

    viewModel.getCurrencies().observe(owner = this) { resource ->
        when (resource.status) {
            SUCCESS -> {
                resource.data?.let {
                    chargeHistoryAdapter = ChargeHistoryDataAdapter(dateFormatter,
                        decimalFormatter,
                        timeFormatter,
                        onItemClickListener = this,
                        currencies = it)
                    chargeHistoryList.adapter = chargeHistoryAdapter
                }
            }
            LOADING, ERROR -> { /** DO NOTHING **/ }
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.chargeHistory.collectLatest {
            chargeHistoryAdapter.submitData(it)
        }
    }

    chargeHistoryAdapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
        if (loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && chargeHistoryAdapter.itemCount < 1) {
            setEmptyViewVisibility(true)
        } else {
            setEmptyViewVisibility(false)
        }
    }
}

   override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}
```

Adapter

```
 class ChargeHistoryDataAdapter(
    private val dateFormatter: DateFormatter,
    private val decimalFormatter: DecimalFormat,
    private val timeFormatter: TimeFormatter,
    private val currencies: List<CurrencyDB>,
    private val onItemClickListener: ListAdapterBase.OnItemClickListener<ChargingSessionDB?>

) : PagingDataAdapter<ChargingSessionDB, ChargeSessionViewHolder>(ChargingSessionDiffUtilCallback()){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChargeSessionViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.charge_history_list_item, parent, false)
        return ChargeSessionViewHolder(view, dateFormatter, decimalFormatter, timeFormatter, currencies)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChargeSessionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindTo(getItem(position), position, onItemClickListener)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
R

Edit after @Tenfour04 suggestion

onActivityCreated

```
viewModel.getCurrencies().observe(owner = viewLifecycleOwner) { resource ->
        when (resource.status) {
            SUCCESS -> {
                Log.d("issueHappening", "viewModel.getCurrencies()")
                resource.data?.let {
                    chargeHistoryAdapter = ChargeHistoryDataAdapter(dateFormatter,
                        decimalFormatter,
                        timeFormatter,
                        onItemClickListener = this,
                        currencies = it)
                    chargeHistoryList.adapter = chargeHistoryAdapter
                }
            }
            LOADING, ERROR -> { /** DO NOTHING **/ }
        }
    }

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.chargeHistory.collectLatest {
                Log.d("issueHappening", "viewModel.chargeHistory")
                chargeHistoryAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't collecting on the right lifecycle. This:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.chargeHistory.collectLatest {
        chargeHistoryAdapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) { 
        viewModel.chargeHistory.collect {
            chargeHistoryAdapter.submitData(it)
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
viewModel.chargeHistory
    .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    .onEach { chargeHistoryAdapter.submitData(it) }
    .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

I changed `collectLatest()` to `collect()` because passing a list to the adapter is a trivial action that will return instantly and has no possible way of being cancelled or needing to be cancelled (I'm assuming it is a non-blocking, non-suspending function). If your collecting takes a long time and is cooperative with cancellation, then it would make sense to use `collectLatest`. There is no `onEachLatest`, but you could possibly use `transformLatest` in place of `onEach` if you needed it.

Likewise with your LiveData observer, you should observe with the `viewLifeCycleOwner`, not the Fragment itself.

```
viewModel.getCurrencies().observe(owner = viewLifecycleOwner) { resource ->
```

Comment: hello @Tenfour04 thank you for responding, I have implemented what you have said,  both the methods `viewModel.getCurrencies()` and `viewModel.chargeHistory` are called once I resume, as per logs but still the recycler view is blank.
When I debug, it does not go into `onCreateViewHolder` of `ChargeHistoryDataAdapter` any idea why this might be happening
I have updated what I have implemented

Comment: I don’t see other problems. `resource.data?.let` is suspicious. Maybe `data` is null. Why is it possible for the data to be null if you always expect it to be available? You might try putting this code in `onViewCreated()` instead. I’ve never used `onActivityCreated()` and maybe I’m missing some detail about the Fragment lifecycle and this isn’t an appropriate place to set up observers. Step through with the debugger in your observers.

Comment: okay thank you I will get back to you, thank you so much for helping out on this